# Accessing field in related table through Foreign Key in Yii

Tags: yii

I have three tables
1. tbl_employee: id(PK), name, position_id(FK), type_id(FK)
2. tbl_position: id, position
3. tbl_type : id, type
I want to display records in field position like what sql does below.

```
SELECT tbl_employee.name, tbl_position.position
FROM tbl_employee, tbl_position
WHERE tbl_employee.position_id = tbl_position.id AND tbl_position.position LIKE '%Designer';
```

In my EmployeeController

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Employee', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
        'select'=>'t.name, tbl_position',
        'with'=>array(
            'position'=>array('select'=>'position'),
        'type'=>array('select'=>'type'),
        ),
         'condition'=>"tbl_position.position LIKE '%Designer'",
    ),      

    ));
    $this->render('index',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,));
}
```

and in my models

```
public function relations(){
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'position' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Position', 'position_id'),
        'type' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Type', 'type_id'),
    );
}
```

and this is my view

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
        array(
            'name'=>'position_id',
            'value'=>CHtml::encode($model->position->position),
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'type_id',
            'value'=>CHtml::encode($model->type->type),
        )
    ),
)); ?>
```

The error I've got is:

> Active record "Employee" is trying to select an invalid column "tbl_position". 
>     Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias.

How can I access position field in tbl_position by using join?What is the correct syntax for achieving that purpose.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
'select'=>'t.name, position.position',

'condition'=>"position.position LIKE '%Designer'",
```

or

```
$model = TblEmployee::model()->with('position','type')->findall(array("condition"=>"position.position LIKE '%Designer'"));
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still gives "Active record "Employee" is trying to select an invalid column "position.position". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias. " The problem is how to access tbl_position through criteria? the only accessible fields are in tbl_employee

Comment: did you try this $model = TblEmployee::model()->with('position','type')->findall(array("condition"=>"position.position LIKE '%Designer'"));

Answer (score 0):

Here I find the solution, but actually your answer was very close

```
public function actionIndex(){
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Employee', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'select'=>'t.name',
                'with'=>array(
                    'position'=>array('select'=>'position'),
                    'type'=>array('select'=>'type'),
                ),
                'condition'=>"position.position LIKE '%Designer'",

            ),      

        ));
        $this->render('index',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,));
    }
```